# How to solve the ESLint in React shows detected higher up in the tree?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

```
> new-app@0.1.0 start C:\Users\sachin\reactjs\new-app
> react-scripts start


There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "eslint": "^6.6.0"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of eslint was detected higher up in the tree:

  C:\Users\sachin\node_modules\eslint (version: 7.10.0)

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

  1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
  2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
  3. Remove "eslint" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
  4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

  5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.

  6. Check if C:\Users\sachin\node_modules\eslint is outside your project directory.
     For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.

  7. Try running npm ls eslint in your project folder.
     This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed eslint.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! new-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the new-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sachin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-09T06_26_24_453Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you try any of the (7!) things suggested in the message? With what result?

Comment: yes I have tried 7 steps even I tried with yarn same result I think it is all about eslint as it shows it requires 6.6.0 this version is present in node modules but it says other version is found

Comment: So you know what installed `C:\Users\sachin\node_modules\eslint` and believe it *should* be there (it wasn't installed by mistake)? Then did you do the thing it says you should do if nothing else works?

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works, try deleting node_modules in one directory back from your project.

Somehow I had node_modules in user/devdirectory, not in user/devdirectory/project